# Connecting firebird database on a local network

Tags: vb.net, firebird

I made a program on vb.net and that has Firebird 2.1 as Database. I have a server also that has Firebird 2.1 and Firebird ODBC installed. What I want to do is to run the program on a client. The problem is it doesn't run and return ERROR like:

`ERROR[08004][ODBC Firebird Driver]Unable to connect to data source:
library 'gds32.dll' failed to load`

If I would install the Firebird 2.1 server to the client - it would return error looking for a database.

What should I do would anyone help me? Any help will be much appreciated.

My project supposed to be like a server-client, where on the server will be the Firebird 2.1 server and Firebird ODBC installed together with the database located at `C:\My_Database\CLIENT_CUSTOMER.FDB` and the application located at the shared files where certain clients can access.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The ODBC driver youre using looks for the `gds32.dll` as the client library - thats the client library name from the InterBase days. If you can change the ODBC datasource's configuration, change it to look for the `fbclient.dll` instead. Or as an alternative, copy the `fbclient.dll` to `system32` directory and rename it to `gds32.dll`.